# Redirect root to named route in rails 4

Tags: redirect, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm trying to redirect my `www.example-app.com` root to `www.example-app.com/app/dashboard` using `routes.rb`. At the moment i'm doing it like so:

```
root to: redirect('/app/dashboard')
```

But would like to do that using named route, for example:

```
get 'app/dashboard' => 'accounts#dashboard', as: :account_dashboard
```

But when i put that in routes:

```
root to: redirect(account_dashboard_url)
```

... of course it doesn't work, how can i do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this directly in routes.rb (as of now – Rails 4.2), but there are ways to make it work. The simplest, IMO, would be to create a method in your application controller to do the redirection.

```
# routes.rb

root to: 'application#redirect_to_account_dashboard'
```

and

```
# application_controller.rb

def redirect_to_account_dashboard
  redirect_to account_dashboard_url
end
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response, have no time really. It looks a bit strange, that there is no "official" way for doing that, must say. But anyway your answer solves my problem. So thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Please note, that as of **Rails 5**, redirecting from the routes is possible.

```rb
match "*", to: redirect('/something-else'), via: :all
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection

This page is quite high on some Google-keywords, and this might be misleading.

Comment: That method is shown in the question itself. The question is about named routes, which I don't believe are supported by `redirect` in Rails 5 or 5.1.

Comment: @frederik-spang look at the very first highlighted section of the question. your answer is not what is what is being asked. the question is only about named routes, not whether redirection is possible at all.